# Make ajax call dependent on another ajax call

Tags: ajax

I would to avoid nesting a bunch of ajax calls inside the 'success' event of one another. I was wondering if someone could guide me in the right direction on how to do something like this? Where one ajax call is dependent on another's return value?

The getLoginAccess() function will be used in many other methods in a similar manner.

If the first one fails i would like to just have it return a 'null' value which i can then take into account before running the second ajax call. Below i demonstrate a psuedo example of what im trying to do.

The method **getLoginAccess** returns a dictionary of data that is required for the second method **createItem** to execute. So only if **getLoginAccess** returns valid data will **createItem** continue on to call the actual ajax call.

Thank you

```
function getLoginAccess() {    
    $.ajax({
        url: '.../api/v1/auth/access_token',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive'
        },
        data: {
            grant_type: 'client_credentials',
            username: 'johnDoe',
            password: '******'
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            return data;
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            return null;
        }
    })
}

function createItem() {

    var login = getLoginAccess();
    if (login == null) {
     return false;
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: '.../api/v1',
        method: 'POST',
        headers = {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'access': `${login.access_token}`
        };
        data: {},
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    })
}

window.onload = function(){
    createItem();
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to refactor the part where the login is verified we could create an intermediate function .. something like this:

> Your login function here

```
function getLoginAccess(){
   // Return login data or null
}
```

> Here we can create an intermediate function to deal with the dependencies of the next execution. If the login returns something other than null, the function passed as a parameter will be executed.

```
function intermediateFunction(functionName,login){
    if(login){
        window[functionName]();
    }
}
```

> Here are the other functions you have created.

```
function createItem() {
   // Do something
}

function listItem() {
   // Do something
}
```

> Here instead of calling the createItem() function you call the intermediary

```
  window.onload = function(){
     intermediateFunction(getLoginAccess(), "createItem");
  };
```

> So basically you would always call the intermediate function that would check the login before calling a particular function. I believe that this is how I would refactor :)

Comment: The getLogin is a function I intend on using a bunch in other functions in a similar manner. What would you recommend for that?

Comment: I think I understand now ... you would like to refactor the login verification ... I just edited my answer. I hope you can help my dear friend :) here's an example of how logic would basically work: https://jsfiddle.net/2r9sd0tv/

Comment: That seems way cleaner. I appreciate you taking the time to help provide a clean example. This helps me out a lot.

Comment: You're welcome, my friend! if the answer helped I would appreciate it very much if you could mark the answer as useful;)

Comment: I can share with you my jsfiddle, it doesn't appear the solution suggested will work. The ajax call works in a way that im not used to handling. It returns null before it finishes.